# sqlite3-ruby can't make on rvm 1.8.7

Tags: sqlite, rvm, sqlite3-ruby

Upgrading to Rails 3 by starting with RVM 1.8.7.  OSX 10.5.8

```
Output:
josh-crewss-macbook:~ joshcrews$ gem install sqlite3-rubyBuilding native extensions.  This could take a while...ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3-ruby:  ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
/Users/joshcrews/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p174/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... yes
checking for sqlite3_libversion_number() in -lsqlite3... yes
checking for rb_proc_arity()... no
checking for sqlite3_column_database_name()... no
checking for sqlite3_enable_load_extension()... no
checking for sqlite3_load_extension()... no
creating Makefile

make
gcc -I. -I. -I/Users/joshcrews/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p174/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-darwin9.8.0 -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/local/include -I/usr/include  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -fno-common -g -O2  -fno-common -pipe -fno-common  -O3 -Wall -Wcast-qual -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion -Wmissing-noreturn -Winline  -c database.c
database.c: In function ‘deallocate’:
database.c:17: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘sqlite3_next_stmt’
database.c:17: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
database.c: In function ‘initialize’:
database.c:76: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘sqlite3_open_v2’
database.c:79: error: ‘SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
database.c:79: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
database.c:79: error: for each function it appears in.)
database.c:79: error: ‘SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
database.c: In function ‘set_sqlite3_func_result’:
database.c:277: error: ‘sqlite3_int64’ undeclared (first use in this function)
database.c: In function ‘rb_sqlite3_func’:
database.c:311: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘ruby_xcalloc’ as signed due to prototype
database.c: In function ‘rb_sqlite3_step’:
database.c:378: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘ruby_xcalloc’ as signed due to prototype
make: *** [database.o] Error 1
```

Gem list (these are under RVM, under system I've got lot more gems included the sqlite3-ruby that's worked for 1.5 years)

```
josh-crewss-macbook:~ joshcrews$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.0.beta3)
actionpack (3.0.0.beta3)
activemodel (3.0.0.beta3)
activerecord (3.0.0.beta3)
activeresource (3.0.0.beta3)
activesupport (3.0.0.beta3, 2.3.8)
arel (0.3.3)
builder (2.1.2)
bundler (0.9.25)
capybara (0.3.8)
configuration (1.1.0)
cucumber (0.7.2)
cucumber-rails (0.3.1)
culerity (0.2.10)
database_cleaner (0.5.2)
diff-lcs (1.1.2)
erubis (2.6.5)
ffi (0.6.3)
gherkin (1.0.30)
i18n (0.4.0, 0.3.7)
json_pure (1.4.3)
launchy (0.3.5)
mail (2.2.1)
memcache-client (1.8.3)
mime-types (1.16)
nokogiri (1.4.2)
polyglot (0.3.1)
rack (1.1.0)
rack-mount (0.6.3)
rack-test (0.5.4)
rails (3.0.0.beta3)
railties (3.0.0.beta3)
rake (0.8.7)
rdoc (2.5.8)
rspec (2.0.0.beta.10, 2.0.0.beta.8)
rspec-core (2.0.0.beta.10, 2.0.0.beta.8)
rspec-expectations (2.0.0.beta.10, 2.0.0.beta.8)
rspec-mocks (2.0.0.beta.10, 2.0.0.beta.8)
rspec-rails (2.0.0.beta.10, 2.0.0.beta.8)
rubygems-update (1.3.7)
selenium-webdriver (0.0.20)
spork (0.8.3)
term-ansicolor (1.0.5)
text-format (1.0.0)
text-hyphen (1.0.0)
thor (0.13.6)
treetop (1.4.8)
trollop (1.16.2)
tzinfo (0.3.22)
webrat (0.7.1)
```

Version of XCode: 3.1.1

My suspicion is it has to do with "-I/Users/joshcrews/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p174/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-darwin9.8.0", because i686-darwin9.8.0 doesnt exist in that file

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I got help at Railsconf from a (the?) sqlite3-ruby gem maintainer, Aaron Patterson

Options:

- Get on Snow Leopard
- Install sqlite3-ruby 1.2.5
- Install sqlite3 via macports first

**Get on Snow Leopard**

sqlite3-ruby >= 1.3.0 not tested for OSX 10.5.  Snow Leopard should work

**Install sqlite3-ruby 1.2.5**

```
gem install sqlite3-ruby -v 1.2.5
```

Then set each Rails3 Gemfile to say this

```
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.2.5', :require => 'sqlite3'
```

**Install sqlite3 via macports first**

```
sudo port install sqlite3
gem install sqlite3-ruby
```

Comment: Thank you, the version dependency helped me too. I was able to solve a similar situation on OS X 10.5 / Ruby 1.8.6 / Rails 2.3.8 with `config.gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :version => '~>1.2.0', :lib => 'sqlite3'`

Comment: As Bryce already mentioned: As alternative to MacPorts, you may want to use homebrew. `brew install sqlite; gem install sqlite3-ruby` solved it beautifully.

Comment: "You must have the SQLite engine installed in order to build this module [sqlite3-ruby]." (http://rubygems.org/gems/sqlite3-ruby)  Hence the `sudo port install sqlite3`, I guess.

Comment: In Rails 3, with a bundler Gemfile, @conny's line would look like `gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '~> 1.2.0', :require => 'sqlite3'`

Comment: Note that Rails 3.1 currently requires sqlite3 ~> 1.3.3 (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-1-stable/Gemfile)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure what is causing the issue, but I got it working by installing sqlite3 via homebrew: http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew

After that, the gem installed just fine.  Leopard's version of sqlite3 must not be compatible with the new version of sqlite3-ruby.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have the sqlite3 macport or brew installed, and you still have the issue, you might have to specify build options when installing the gem.

Example:

```
gem install sqlite3 -v 1.3.5 -- --with-sqlite3-include=/opt/local/include --with-sqlite3-lib=/opt/local/lib
```

If you're on homebrew, use /usr/local instead of /opt/local .

To configure bundler to remember the build options for sqlite3 (run "bundle help config" for more info):

```
bundle config build.sqlite3 --with-sqlite3-include=/opt/local/include --with-sqlite3-lib=/opt/local/lib
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue on Linux, and runs bellow two commands. Works perfectly.

```
sudo aptitude install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby
```